# FIQL/RQL or RESTful query parsers PHP implementations

Tags: php, api

**RESTful queries: FIQL/RQL**

I'm looking for implementations for [FIQL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-atompub-fiql-00) in context of RESTful application. The thing which I'm looking for previously was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371610/rest-rql-java-implementation) on SO, but I'm looking for implementations, written in PHP. So far I did some research and found [javascript](https://github.com/persvr/rql) and [java](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser) implementations, but it still not possible to use in my project.

Second thing is - that I actually have no strict requirement on FIQL - and, if any decent alternative for FIQL or RQL exists with PHP implementation, I will appreciate any suggestions.

Of course, since FIQL has it's own RFC, last option would be - implement parser by myself, but, due to timeline conditions that would be the last thing to do and I need to be sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel before start doing that.

**Question**

So, are there any decent **PHP** implementations for RESTful query language, which is URI-friendly and work **both** ways (i.e. not only construct a request, which is, obviously, an easy thing to do, but also to **parse** it back)?

> <sub>1. Despite similar (mentioned) question exists on SO, it's normally not welcome there to ask questions about third-party libraries/implementations/stuff-like-that, so asking there. Hope it's a proper SE site for that, but if not - please, guide to the correct one.</sub>

> <sub>2. I can not create tags. Proper would be [rest](/questions/tagged/rest), [rql](/questions/tagged/rql), [fiql](/questions/tagged/fiql) together with [php](/questions/tagged/php)</sub>

Comment: Update: was not able to find any library for my requirements. Written own implementation for partial FIQL and goals of the API of the project.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, it seems no PHP implementation exists so far..
We also need one for our company and it looks like we're writing one ourselves - will be located at https://github.com/libgraviton/php-rql-parser ;-)

We will need some weeks for any progress from our side (ppl going on holiday); but check back there later or maybe consider to contribute..

Comment: No need anymore, since I've decided to implement parser by myself. So partial implementation of FIQL with respect of our needs. But anyway - thanks for the answer and good luck with your project